# Mongo Replication

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have a mongo 2.4.8 database setup and running in a live environment. I am wanting to add a replica however I would like to use the latest version 3.2.9 for the replica.

Is the only way for me to do this to upgrade the current node to version 3.2.9 then add the replica?

My plan would be sync all the data to the new node make it primary then update the old node to the latest version is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can create a new node and make a replica, and update the old node.
few things to keep in mind are:-

- The default storage engine for 3.2.9 will be wiredtiger and for 2.4.8 it will be mmapv1, so you would have to change the configuration so that you can keep on using mmapv1 as your storage engine.
- Do replication very carefully. if not done properly, there are chances that the whole database is blown. i recommend you to take the backup of the database before doing replication

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with the first method that you mentioned. Upgrade the current stand alone database and then create a replica set. I tried to find the best practice from Mongodb, but I couldn't find an answer. So, I asked Adam [ex employee of MongoDB and creator M202 course](https://twitter.com/comerford) to find his opinion.

[Source: Adam, ex employee of Mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o94qr.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have gone with the route of a full mongo backup then restore into the new nodes.

The replication old to new was very fragile plus the backup is very fast to do as long as you allowed to bring the server down.